# How to pronounce dates like: "le six avril" and "le trois octobre"

Tags: prononciation

Good old French number pronunciation!

Already scratching my head over how to teach my little first-grade students without completely confusing them that "six" is pronounced [sees] when by itself, [see] before a consonant, and [seez] before a vowel...

Now I realised that I'm not sure myself how to pronounce "six" before a month in a date. Should it be "le [sees] avril" or "le [seez] avril"?

Also, is the final consonant of "deux" and "trois" pronounced or silent before months starting with a vowel, as in "le [trwa] octobre" or "le [trwaz] octobre"?

Comment: Much to be learned from [this thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/liaison-in-dix-neuf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liaison in dix-neuf](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/liaison-in-dix-neuf)

Answer (score 4):

La règle générale est qu'il y a deux cas. *Six* se prononce [sis] lorsqu'il est à la fin d'un nombre qui est utilisé tout seul (le nombre est alors un nom ou pronom).

> Le numéro six est sorti. [le.ny.me.ʁo.**sis**.ɛ.sɔʁ]
>   Le numéro vingt-six est sorti. [le.ny.me.ʁo.vɛ̃t.**sis**.ɛ.sɔʁ]
>   Le six du mois. [le.**sis**.dy.mwa]

On prononce [si]/[siz] lorsque le nombre qualifie un nom (le nombre est alors déterminant). Dans ce cas, on suit les règles habituelles de la [liaison](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais): [si] avant un son consomme ou un H aspiré, [siz] avant un son voyelle ou un H muet. Il s'agit d'une liaison obligatoire (déterminant ou adjectif précédant le nom).

> Six œufs. [**si**.z‿ø]
>   Six grands œufs. [**si**.gʁɑ̃.z‿ø]
>   Six hérissons. [**si**.e.ʁi.sɔ̃]
>   Six hommes et six femmes. [**si**.zɔ.me.si.fam]
>   Six mille six cents. [**si**.mil.**si**.sɑ̃]

La règle est la même pour *dix*, avec en plus un cas particulier: [*dix-neuf* [**diz**.nœf]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/liaison-in-dix-neuf).

Pour *un*, *deux* et *trois*, la règle est simple : la consonne finale est muette, et on fait la liaison normalement.

Pour *huit*, on prononce en la consonne finale lorsque le mot est à la fin d'un nombre utilisé tout seul. Sinon la consonne finale est muette et on fait la liaison s'il le faut. Pour *cinq*, suivant les régions, la règle peut être la même, ou on peut prononcer le [k] même devant une consonne, mais on prononce rarement le [k] à l'intérieur d'un nombre (cinq mille cinq cent vingt-cinq [sɛ̃.mil.sɛ̃.sɑ̃.vɛ̃t.sɛ̃k]). Pour *vingt*, il y a des règles particulières [avec des variations régionales](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/pronunciation-of-vingt).

Pour *neuf*, il y a un cas particulier : on prononce en général [nœf] (la consonne finale se prononce toujours), mais [nœv] voire [nøv] devant quelques noms qui commencent par une voyelle (neuf ans [nœ.v‿ɑ̃], neuf heures [nœ.v‿œʁ] ou [nø.v‿œʁ]).

Si l'on veut suivre la règle générale, pour savoir comment prononcer « trois avril », « six avril », etc., il faut savoir si le nombre est un déterminant ou non. Grammaticalement, c'est très simple : le nombre n'est pas un déterminant, sinon le nom serait au pluriel. Il s'agit donc de deux noms apposés. Logiquement, on devrait donc prononcer le nombre indépendamment du nom de mois : [**tʁwa**.a.vʁil], [**sis**.a.vʁil], etc. Mais en fait on a plutôt tendance à considérer que même si le nombre n'est pas un déterminant, il fait quand même partie d'une construction où il précède forcément le nom, et donc on prononce comme si c'était un déterminant, et on fait la liaison (ou on ne prononce pas la consonne finale du nombre si le mois commence par une consonne). Cela donne donc les prononciations les plus courantes : trois avril [[**tʁwa.z‿**a.vʁil]], six avril [[**si.z‿**a.vʁil]], six mai [[**si**.mɛ]], huit mai [[**ɥi**.mɛ]], …

Voir aussi [La Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3137) (qui m'informe qu'il n'y a pas de différence entre le Québec et la France sur la prononciation de *six* et *dix*).

Answer (score 1):

You have to prononce the following:

For 6:

> "le [seez] avril"

For 3:

> "le [trwaz] octobre"

Because they precede both respectively the **vowels** "a" and "o"

*Others examples:*

> "le [sees] Janvier"
>
> "le [trwa] Janvier"

Because they precede consonants "J".

Comment: « le [sis] avril » est aussi possible.