# “81” pronunciation—pronounce the “t” ou non?

Tags: prononciation

[image]

I googled the pronunciation of “81” in French and got what I’m 81% sure is an incorrect pronunciation (see attached image) since there’s no “et” in the number like the pronunciation suggestion implies. (Edit: I also just noticed they spell “vingt” wrong.)

Then this answer ( https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7569 ) states that the “t” is never pronounced in 81, regardless of region. Which is wild to me, considering certain regions allegedly pronounce the “t” in the standalone “vingt.”

Google Translate’s voice does not pronounce the “t” in 81 either. I’d just like some additional confirmation since “quatre-vingt-un” sounds slurred to me without pronouncing the “t”

Comment: The spelling is also wrong…

Comment: Since you don't have any other concerns than those already discussed in that linked question, I'm closing this as a duplicate.